# Redirect stderr to error handler

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling, io-redirection

Is it possible to pass a stderr message to an error handler function and have it decide how the message should be handled? 
A quick example would be if a script that if the user gives foo.bar non-existent files to copy or only gives it one input parameters. Instead of printing the system error messages immediately, I want to print some additional information first. Also tee it into log.txt.

This is what I have thought of so far but it does not seem to work.

```
#foo.bar
function errhand
{
  read IN #read stdout which has stderr redirected.
  echo "an error occurred while copying." | tee -a log.txt
  echo $IN | tee -a log.txt
}

cp $1 $2 || errhand 2>&1   #redirect stder to stdout if error occurs.
```

Comment: in your example, `cp` has already emitted it's std-err msg, before it can be see after the `||`. . I think you want something like `cp $1 $2 2>&1 | errhand` (although I appreciapte the appeal of only running `errhand` if the prev cmd emitted an error.) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the standard error of the `cp` command to `errhand`, which can simply return if there is no text to output.

```
errhand () {
    read errormsg
    [[ -z $errormsg ]] && return
    { echo "an error occurred"
      echo "$IN"
    } | tee -a log.txt
}

cp "$1" "$2" 2> >(errhand)
```